# Erro ao installar mongodb no windows

Tags: windows, mongodb

Tentei instalar o mongo db no windows. Faço todo o processo de instalação porém quando a instalação chega próximo de ser finalizada os arquivos e a pasta de instalação do mongo são apagadas. Ocorre um erro e a instalação é abortada.

> "setup wizard ended prematurely because of an error.your system has not been modified.To. Install this program at a later time run setup wizard again.click finish button to exit the setup."

1. Sistema operacional: WIN 10 64 bits.
2. MongoDB: 3.6.

Alguém já passou por isso ?

Comment: Estranho, sem erro ? Nada ?

Comment: Vejo a pasta sendo criada na hora da instalação.  Aí quando termina tudo e apagado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você  já verificou se tem permissão para realizar a instalação no diretório sugerido pelo MongoDB? Por padrão, os arquivos de instalação ficam neste diretório:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\
```

Você já tentou instalar em um outro diretório? Por exemplo:

```
C:\Users\moisolas\Documents
```

Caso não resolva, sugiro:

- Seria interessante utlizar algum programa que realize a limpeza de resíduos de instaladores, por exemplo, o Ccleaner...
- Tem algum anti-virus instalado? Tente pausar a proteção em tempo real dele e realizar a instalação do `MongoDB`.

Comment: Olá. Já tentei instalar em outro diretório. Ainda não fiz uma limpeza no registro. Vou fazê-lo. Só possuo o Windows defender instalado. Vou fazer as recomendações

Answer (score 0):

Não sei porque isso acontece exatamente porém os passos abaixo me ajudou a resolver o problema.

1. Desmarcar a opção Compass install
2. Concluir a instalação
3. Rodar o instalador novamente:
4. Marcar a opção Compass install.